# First JavaServerFaces effort

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss

I’m trying run jsf page with value from bean:
test.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <p> Text: #{testBean.text} </p>
</h:body>

</html>
```

TestBean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    private String text;

    public TestBean(){
        text = "Text" + new Date();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

But when I run this page on JBoss I get only “Text:”. Source of page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title></head><body>
    <p> Text:  </p></body>

</html>
```

Where can be problem? I'm using jboss-as-7.1.1.Final and Intellij IDEA.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured your web.xml file to mapping servlet about JSF functionalities? Please go here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/ to further information

Comment: Yes, I have. Now I'm tryed to copy web.xml from your example, But result is same.

Comment: Instead of <p> use tag <h:outputText value="Text: #{testBean.text}" />. Tell me if it's OK

Comment: Thanks, but no, it does not help. I'm tryed add logging to bean, in getText() - l.log(Level.ALL,"asd");. When I use this bean from jsp: <jsp:useBean id="test" class="TestBean"></jsp:useBean>
<p>Text: <jsp:getProperty name="test" property="text"/></p>. All is fine i see information in browser and in log file. But when I use /test.faces I dont see information in broser and in log file...

Comment: Have you put in your faces-config.xml these lines?  <application>
  <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
 </application>

Comment: Nope, now I set it and I get error on all my pages: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton is not set. Is your Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() set correctly?

Comment: Dear, I've found another link. If you use JSF 2.0 your faces-config.xml must become: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/ch13s05.html I hope for you ;)